# Show that $5 \mathbb{Z} +8= 5\mathbb{Z} +3= 5\mathbb{Z} +(-2)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show the following equalities $5 \mathbb{Z} +8= 5\mathbb{Z} +3= 5\mathbb{Z} +(-2)$.

$5 \mathbb{Z} +8=\{5z_{1}+8: z_{1} \in \mathbb{Z}\}$,

$5 \mathbb{Z} +3=\{5z_{2}+3: z_{2} \in \mathbb{Z}\}$,

$5 \mathbb{Z} +(-2)=\{5z_{3}+(-2): z_{3} \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

So, how can prove to use these defitions?

Comment: I think you mean $5\Bbb Z+3,5\Bbb Z+(-2)$.

Comment: Once you edit this problem so that it makes sense, it is extremely similar to your [recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790221/show-that-mathbbz-mathbbz-mathbbz).  Can you apply the methods of the solution you were given to that one here?

Comment: Hint: what will you get if you define $z_2=z_1+1$?

Comment: Perhaps writing the sets in a more precise (yet, pedantic) way might help you; for instance: $$5\Bbb Z+8=\{z\in\Bbb Z\,:\,\exists z_1\in\Bbb Z,\ z=5z_1+8\}$$

Comment: **Hint:-** $a+\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{5\mathbb{Z}}=b+\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{5\mathbb{Z}}\iff b-a\in 5\mathbb{Z}$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @lulu Can you see my answer?

Comment: Looks good (+1)!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You need to show that $8$, $3$, and $-2$ are all in the same coset of $5\mathbb Z$. Said differently, you need to show that
$8-3$, $8-(-2)$, and $3-(-2)$ are all in $5\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a \in 5\mathbb Z + 8$, then there is $b\in\mathbb Z$ such that $a = 5b + 8$. Then you can do
\begin{align*}
a = 5b + 8 = 5(b-1) + 3,
\end{align*}
thus $a\in5\mathbb Z + 3$. This proves
$$
5\mathbb Z + 8 \subseteq 5\mathbb Z + 3,
$$
because every element of $5\mathbb Z + 8$ is an element of $5\mathbb Z + 3$.

With a similar trick you can show $5\mathbb Z + 3 \subseteq 5\mathbb Z + 8$ which implies then $5\mathbb Z + 3 = 5\mathbb Z + 8$.

Your other claim is analog.

Answer (score 1):

We have $5 \mathbb{Z}+8=5\mathbb{Z}+5+3=5(\mathbb{Z}+1)+3$. So, $\mathbb{Z}+1$ =$\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $5 \mathbb{Z}+8= 5 \mathbb{Z}+3$.

Now, we will show $5 \mathbb{Z}+3=5 \mathbb{Z}+(-2)$.
$5 \mathbb{Z}+3=$5 $\mathbb{Z}+5-2=5$ $(\mathbb{Z}+1)+(-2)$. Thus,$5 \mathbb{Z}+3=5 \mathbb{Z}+(-2)$.

Therefore, $5 \mathbb{Z}+8=5 \mathbb{Z}+3=5 \mathbb{Z}+(-2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ you have $\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z} + n$.

Thus, $5 \mathbb{Z} +8 = 5 \mathbb{Z} + 5 + 3 = 5 (\mathbb{Z} + 1)+ 3 = 5\mathbb{Z} + 3$.

Similarly, you have  $5 \mathbb{Z} + 8 = 5 \mathbb{Z} + 10 - 2 = 5\mathbb{Z} - 2$.